# How to call precompile with original parameters rather than types?

Tags: julia

I have custom julia module with a function taking in the path of a CSV file and produce a corresponding plot using CairoMakie. But compilation of the function takes too long (more than 5mins) i.e. first call is too slow. So, I want to precompile the function along with the precompilation of the module. But calling precompile with type is meaningless as path is a string and will not bear the type of the original file.
So, is there any way to call precompile with original parameters?

```
precompile(f, (String,)) #this is not helpful

precompile(f, ("abc.csv",)) #this is required, calling with original parameter(here with the file name).
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why the path argument being a `String` matters here. You're likely processing it within the function - perhaps with a `CSV.read` or `CSV.File` - and there should be enough information in the code for useful precompilation to happen. Have you tried `precompile(f, (String,))`, and found that it didn't help?

In any case, one change you can try (which is probably good design anyway) is to use multiple dispatch: once you receive the CSV file's path in your (existing) `f(csvpath::String)` method and extracted the data from the file (for eg., as a `DataFrame` with `CSV.read`, or as a `CSV.File`), pass that on to a method of `f` specialized to that type (either `f(::DataFrame)` or `f(::CSV.File)`) and do further processing and plotting there. You can then precompile this more type-specific method with a `precompile(f, (DataFrame,))` or `precompile(f, (CSV.File,))`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried precompile(f, (String,)) and it does not improve (maybe little, I have not noticed).